# Jlist IS not Visible on the Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When I Add the JList to the Frame   I Add it As Scroll Pane   , But the frame becomes empty  when i do this 
Here is My Code

```
frame2 = new JFrame();
    frame2.setBounds(100, 100, 543, 432);
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame2.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JList list = new JList(names);
    list.setBounds(36, 11, 161, 345);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(10);



frame2.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(list));


    JList list_1 = new JList(access);
    list_1.setBounds(356, 11, 161, 345);
    list_1.setVisibleRowCount(10);

    frame2.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(list_1));

    frame2.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: @Reimeus  Iam using the Absolute Layout Is there is any way i can Make it Work With Absoulte Layout or the problem is related to the place of the jlist on the Frame ?

Comment: @genralHummel you mean both `JList`s dont show up ?

Comment: @benjaminc   Yes Both Of them   When i add them As   " frame2.getContentPane().add(list_1)  "  they work But they are static they dont show up the whole list

Comment: @benjaminc Thanks For Your Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to avoid such problems. When you for some reasons want to avoid using of them, you must provide size for the scroll panes, you use.

```
frame2 = new JFrame();
frame2.setBounds(100, 100, 543, 432);
frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame2.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

JList list = new JList(names);
list.setVisibleRowCount(10);

JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(list);
scroller.setBounds(36, 11, 161, 345);

frame2.getContentPane().add(scroller);


JList list_1 = new JList(access);

list_1.setVisibleRowCount(10);

scroller = new JScrollPane(list_1);
scroller.setBounds(356, 11, 161, 345);
frame2.getContentPane().add(scroller);

frame2.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Those `JList`s do not shot up because incorrect order of components, here try this.

Remove `setBounds()` from `JList`s and set bounds of `JScrollPane`s. Then add lists to scroll panes.

```
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
frame2 = new JFrame();
frame2.setBounds(100, 100, 543, 432);
frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame2.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

JList list = new JList(names);
list.setVisibleRowCount(10);

JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
jScrollPane.setBounds(36, 11, 161, 345);
frame2.getContentPane().add(jScrollPane);

JList list_1 = new JList(access);
list_1.setVisibleRowCount(10);

JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(list_1);
jScrollPane1.setBounds(356, 11, 161, 345);
frame2.getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);

frame2.setVisible(true);
```